# Verify Unity, Oculus app on server side

Tags: unity, server, virtual-reality, security, oculus

Starting with the fact that my background is non-technical, I have used a keystore with my Unity game build that is for Oculus, Rift, etc. Now I want to verify the authenticity of incoming client requests on my game server (that is using ASP.NET CORE but I have reason to believe the steps are standardized regardless of the framework used). For example to detect if the application has been rebuilt by someone else.

I know it is quite possible to include a certificate or hash within request bodies, since all communication is encrypted anyways. Would this approach be riskier? My main concern here is that apps can be decompiled and the constants retrieved, so including keys outside of the build process seems risky.

Please guide me in this topic.

For those who want to see my existing approach, here is another question on this on overflow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76952659/how-to-verify-signing-key-of-unity-game-client-from-dotnetcore-server

Edit:
Currently doing the same via https://developer.oculus.com/documentation/unity/ps-attestation-api/

Comment: With enough dedication, it is possible to almost always find a workaround. What is your main concern you have in terms of game impact? Bots, gold/ item duplication/ hacks, wall hacks, etc. An application does not need to be rebuild to have been tampered with, there can be simple memory manipulation or dll injection.

Comment: Sorry, but what you want to do is not technically possible. The question I linked as a duplicate is about Java, not Unity, but that doesn't really change anything, because you are dealing with limitations of the Internet itself. There is simply no way to authenticate that the software you are talking with via a network is indeed the software you think it is and not a clone that behaves in the same way and has access to the same data.

Comment: I am more in need of guidance how to make a deterrent, not a perfect solution that cannot exist.

Comment: @Zibelas Forgot to tag you, I am more in need of guidance how to make a deterrent, not a perfect solution that cannot exist

Comment: Different needs have different solutions, without knowing what exactly you want to prevent (or detect), the answer won't be focused. Gold is trivial with server validation. Let the client have as much as it wants, won't help with shopping. You can't prevents bots, but if you add some invisible enemies or obstacles and you have users that are dodging or trying to attack those, you know at least who might be a bot and can react accordingly. Wallhacks can be prevented by not sending information to the client that it should not have. And so on